# list of tables and list of variables to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have potentially thousands of tables that I want to extract specific variables from each table, convert to an individual data frame, name it with a "df_prefix and subsequently analyze. The starting tables are:

```
activities
  line_number    id       name  startdate
1       21000 ab123   John Doe 2010-11-01
2       23400 cd456 Peter Gynn 2008-03-25
3       26800 ef789 Jolie Hope 2007-03-14
```

and:

```
 classifications
  id var1 var2
1  1    a    1
2  2    b    1
3  3    c    0
4  4    d    0
5  5    e    1
```

The output I would like for the activity table and classifications tables are:

```
activities[,c("id", "line_number", "name")]
     id line_number       name
1 ab123       21000   John Doe
2 cd456       23400 Peter Gynn
3 ef789       26800 Jolie Hope
```

and the classifications table:

```
  classifications[, c("id")]
1                          1
2                          2
3                          3
4                          4
5                          5
```

I have looked at using list2df and list2env.  I am not really sure what to do..tables[[[1]][,fields[[1]]] defintely doesnt work..

```
#Make a fake activities table
line_number <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
id <- c('ab123','cd456','ef789')
name <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
activities <- data.frame(line_number,id,name, startdate, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#Make a fake classifications table
classifications <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))

#Make list of tables and list of specific fields we need
fields <- list(a = c("id", "line_number", "name"), c = "id")
tables<-list("activities","classifications")
```

Comment: Could you add(copy-paste it to the question) what the final output should look like?! I think it's easier to think of a solution by looking at the expected output before running code.

Comment: The question has been updated to included the starting data and hope for result..

Comment: Hi, I have made progress.

Answer (score 0):

This works but I wonder if there is a way to to name the tables automatically instead of replicating the original list of dataframes i.e. table_names. Ideally I would like to give it a list of the dataframes and it automatically names them..

```
#Make a fake activities table
line_number <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
id <- c('ab123','cd456','ef789')
name <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
activities <- data.frame(line_number,id,name, startdate, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#Make a fake classifications table
classifications <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))

#Make list of tables and list of specific fields we need
fields <- list(a = c("id", "line_number", "name"), c = "id")
tables<-list(activities,classifications)
#table_names<-list("activities_df", "classifications_df") #This is clunky
table_names<-names(Filter(isTRUE, eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame)))

for(i in 1:length(tables)) {
x=tables[[i]]
y=fields[[i]]
z<-as.data.frame(x[,y])
name <- paste(table_names[i],sep="") 
assign(name,z) 
}
```